# Can we use Bootstrap in OpenUI5 / SAPUI5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sapui5

For my work I should create an app with openUI5 which should be fully responsive. I normally use Bootstrap for this, but i don't know how to integrate Bootstrap in an OpenUI5 app. Any ideas?

Comment: openUI5 **is** fully responsive. Or at least it should be. :)

Comment: Yes, but I really would like to reuse my existing bootstrap themes and templates in my app, and it seems OpenUI5 has a quite different markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at [Ui5Strap](http://ui5strap.com) which provides a Bootstrap library for OpenUI5. It is still alpha state, but it seems to support the 3.1.1 Bootstrap library already quite well. But like the previous commenter mentioned, OpenUI5 should be fully responsive by default, too - so you should consider if you really want to build your app upon a third party library.